# Is there a term like 'metaphor' but for drawing a disanalogy?

Tags: rhetoric, rhetorical-devices

Similes and metaphors drawn analogies, compare things. Is there another rhetorical term for when someone wants to draw a ***disanalogy***?

I can imagine a poet or at least rhetorician wanting to say e.g. that their lover's eyes are *not like* pearls, but far lovelier.

Comment: Are you looking for "a lack of analogy" then it is "disanalogy"  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disanalogy

Comment: @P.O. yes but as a figure of speech.

Comment: Would something like "he cannot be the one for there is no thunder in his heart or heart in his step" be the sort of thing you are trying to find a term for? Would it still not be a metaphor even if it is negated?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at *dissimile*?

> a [rhetorical] comparison of two dissimilar objects for the purpose of illustration

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/dissimile

Answer (score 0):

If the contrast is explicit then it's exactly that, a literary contrast.

> In literature, an author uses contrast when he or she describes the
>   difference(s) between two or more entities. For example, in the first
>   four lines of William Shakespeare's Sonnet 130, Shakespeare contrasts
>   a mistress to the sun, coral, snow, and wire.
>
> [Contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(literary)) is the antonym of simile

Not sure if an *implicit contrast* has a term